# How to get rid of configparser.NoOptionError in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

```
DEBUG = eval(ctx.get(CONFIGSECTION, 'DEBUG'))

# MDM Revert before prod!
# DEBUG=True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

REDIS_SERVER = ctx.get(CONFIGSECTION, 'REDIS_SERVER')
REDIS_DB = ctx.get(CONFIGSECTION, 'REDIS_DB')
```

I am getting below error

```
raise NoOptionError(option, section)
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'debug' in section: 'DEFAULT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please derive a new config parser class from RawConfigParser, adding in only the new special behavior, like so:
Please read this document:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser, NoOptionError
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

class MyConfigParser(RawConfigParser):
    def get(self, section, option):
        try:
            return RawConfigParser.get(self, section, option)
        except NoOptionError:
            return None

settings=StringIO('''
[Set]
ip=192.0.2.76
verify=yes
[Set2]
ip=192.0.2.74
''')

cfg=MyConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
cfg.readfp(settings)

assert cfg.get('Set', 'verify') ==  'yes'
assert cfg.get('Set2', 'verify') == None
```